# Dynamically replace <a> href (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, anchor

I have list of objects coming back to me. Sometimes that list will include download links, those download links have to be authorized through another request and the response from that request gives me the new URL I need to use in the `<a>`

I am looking to dynamically be able to replace the href inside of the `<a>` depending on criteria I determine. So sometimes the `<a>` will be unchanged and sometimes I will replace the href with a new URL

For example get this initially

```
<a href='www.link1.com'>First Link</a>
```

And would like to change it conditionally to this

```
<a href='www.link2.com'>Second Link</a>
```

Comment: Can't you use `href` as a prop? Let parent change the `href` whatever it want.